Winscp and Putty connection is closed randomly to my Rocyk Linux server
Using VPN I am connecting to my Rocky server 9.3. running Virtual Machine my connection is disconected randomly. After being disconnected I cannot reconnect for about a minute or two. Connection is refused. I tried from different computers from different networks and the same error occurred. Only connections inside the main network work (Winscp from another windows server to Rocky server stays on all the time). I am using PfSense as firewall etc.
I already set the keep connection alive parameters, nothing suspicious in the logs on server side. . I am kind of running in the dark here.
Any suggestions??
Some of the logs:
Knocking FTP port.
. 2024-08-21 11:35:02.610 FTP port did not open.
* 2024-08-21 11:35:02.693 (EFatal) Network error: Connection to "192.168.178.205" refused.
. 2024-08-21 11:35:06.189 Looking up host "192.168.178.205" for SSH connection
. 2024-08-21 11:35:06.189 Connecting to 192.168.178.205 port 22
. 2024-08-21 11:35:08.287 Failed to connect to 192.168.178.205: Network error: Connection refused
. 2024-08-21 11:35:08.287 Knocking FTP port.
. 2024-08-21 11:35:10.302 FTP port did not open.
* 2024-08-21 11:35:10.368 (EFatal) Network error: Connection to "192.168.178.205" refused.

/Var/log/secure
Aug 21 14:49:01 localhost sshd[17356]: Connection from 172.16.17.4 port 49860 on 192.168.178.205 port 22 rdomain ""
Aug 21 14:49:05 localhost sshd[17356]: Accepted password for woshi from 172.16.17.4 port 49860 ssh2
Aug 21 14:49:05 localhost sshd[17360]: Starting session: subsystem 'sftp' for woshi from 172.16.17.4 port 49860 id 0
Aug 21 14:49:30 localhost sshd[17390]: Connection from 172.16.17.4 port 49945 on 192.168.178.205 port 22 rdomain ""
Aug 21 14:49:58 localhost sshd[17390]: Accepted password for woshi from 172.16.17.4 port 49945 ssh2
Aug 21 14:49:58 localhost sshd[17396]: Starting session: shell on pts/1 for woshi from 172.16.17.4 port 49945 id 0
Aug 21 14:52:16 localhost sshd[17440]: Connection from 172.16.17.4 port 50512 on 192.168.178.205 port 22 rdomain ""
Aug 21 14:52:17 localhost sshd[17440]: Accepted password for woshi from 172.16.17.4 port 50512 ssh2
Aug 21 14:52:17 localhost sshd[17444]: Starting session: subsystem 'sftp' for woshi from 172.16.17.4 port 50512 id 0
Aug 21 14:53:23 localhost sshd[17509]: Connection from 172.16.17.4 port 50739 on 192.168.178.205 port 22 rdomain ""
Aug 21 14:53:23 localhost sshd[17509]: Accepted password for woshi from 172.16.17.4 port 50739 ssh2
Aug 21 14:53:24 localhost sshd[17513]: Starting session: shell for woshi from 172.16.17.4 port 50739 id 0
Aug 21 14:53:28 localhost sshd[17546]: Connection from 172.16.17.4 port 50757 on 192.168.178.205 port 22 rdomain ""
Aug 21 14:53:32 localhost sshd[17546]: Failed none for woshi from 172.16.17.4 port 50757 ssh2
Aug 21 14:53:59 localhost sshd[17546]: Accepted password for woshi from 172.16.17.4 port 50757 ssh2
Aug 21 14:54:00 localhost sshd[17556]: Starting session: shell on pts/0 for woshi from 172.16.17.4 port 50757 id 0
Aug 21 15:09:06 localhost sshd[17360]: Timeout, client not responding from user woshi 172.16.17.4 port 49860
Aug 21 15:11:30 localhost sshd[17396]: Timeout, client not responding from user woshi 172.16.17.4 port 49945
Aug 21 15:18:25 localhost sshd[17513]: Timeout, client not responding from user woshi 172.16.17.4 port 50739
Aug 21 15:21:18 localhost sshd[17444]: Timeout, client not responding from user woshi 172.16.17.4 port 50512
Aug 21 15:21:28 localhost sshd[17556]: Timeout, client not responding from user woshi 172.16.17.4 port 50757

UPDATE:
So my network is managed by pfSense. I am connecting to that network over OpenVPN. My Rocky Linux server (target server) is on VmWare virtual machine.

Update the question as to how the systems are all connected together, including details of any intermediate systems.
